# Can I place more than one arrow on the same node? (Graphviz)

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to do something like this with graphviz, is it possible?
My problem is placing more than one arrow towards the same node,just like in node "q" (Use another tool for this)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes you can e.g.:

```
digraph G {
  "To":n -> "To":n
  "To":ne -> "To":ne
  "To":nw -> "To":nw
}
```